# how can I run a qt application in another pc from the one it was develop on

Tags: qt, shared-library

I just want to give the executable, and perhaps let the other user (also running ubuntu) to download the qt5 library (non development version) in order to run the application.

I am not interested in compiling a static version of qt just to make this executable self contained.

checking with `ldd` I went on to get the specific libs that seem necessary

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5core5a libqt5gui5 libqt5widgets5 libqt5network5 libqt5printsupport5
```

says that I already have the latest versions installed.

Still the application does not run. what is wrong? which runtime libs should I get in order to get the executable find all the symbols?

Comment: Have you tried to follow the [Linux deployment documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-deployment.html)?

Comment: @gsxruk Hi there. It has not been very helpful. Regarding the shared libraries (which is how  I prefer to proceed), it only contains an example for the plugandplay and plugandplay plugins.  To be honest I don't even know why this is there, but info about the libraries is absent. Is there really no ubuntu packages for qt5 in the repositories?????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe there are several methods that can be used. I have listed one method below and this is the recommended method in the deployment documentation that I gave in the comment.

I'm using a standard new Qt Widgets Application project named HelloWorld for this example and this has been compiled in release mode and the resulting file is named "HelloWorld". This example also assumes you are using x64.

Assuming we start with a root folder named MyApp, copy the "HelloWorld" executable to it. The following libraries then need to be copied from QtInstallationFolder/gcc_64/lib to this folder:

- libicudata
- libicui18n
- libicuuc
- libQt5Core
- libQt5DBus
- libQt5Gui
- libQt5Widgets
- libQt5XcbQpa

Also, copy the following library from QtInstallationFolder/gcc_64/plugins/platforms to MyApp/platforms:

- libqxcb

Copy and paste the following into a text editor and save this into the MyApp folder as HelloWorld.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
appname=`basename $0 | sed s,\.sh$,,`

dirname=`dirname $0`
tmp="${dirname#?}"

if [ "${dirname%$tmp}" != "/" ]; then
dirname=$PWD/$dirname
fi
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$dirname
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
$dirname/$appname "$@"
```

You should then be able to run the application from the application root folder with:

```
./HelloWorld.sh
```

The above represents the minimum libraries required for a GUI application. If you use this method for your application and that uses any further libraries than those listed above, you would also need to copy these to the root MyApp folder.  Also, when you create the .sh file, use the name of your application.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you! I wonder why would it be so difficult to have such a clear answer from Qt documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to deploy the application, for this purpose I use the utility
[cqtdeployer](https://github.com/QuasarApp/Console-QtDeployer)

You can install from [github](https://github.com/QuasarApp/Console-QtDeployer/releases) releases

or

from [snapstore](https://snapcraft.io/cqtdeployer)

```
sudo snap install cqtdeployer
```

You can use as follows:

```
cqtdeployer -bin myApp -qmake path/to/my/qmake -qmlDir path/to/my/qml/files/dir
```

And Run application with sh script

If you'll use the version from snap then make sure that you have all the permissions.